# Connecting to AspNetCore SignalR Server from another machine on the same LAN

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, signalr, blazor-server-side

HubServer.Program.cs:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{

  getRegistrySettings();

  WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

  // Add services to the container.
  builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
  builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
  builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
  builder.Services.AddResponseCompression(opts =>
  {
    opts.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
        new[] { "application/octet-stream" });
  });

  builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
  {
    options.AddPolicy("CORSPolicy", builder =>
    builder.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials().SetIsOriginAllowed((hosts) => true));
  });


  WebApplication app = builder.Build();

  // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
  if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
  {
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
  }

  //CORS need to be enabled for calling SignalR service 
  app.UseCors("CORSPolicy");

  //app.UseHttpsRedirection();

  app.UseStaticFiles();

  app.UseRouting();

  app.MapBlazorHub();

  app.MapHub<MCHub>("/mchub");

  //app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

  app.Run();
}
```

To access the Hub I use:

WPF App:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //const string url = "http://localhost:5289/mchub";
    const string url = "http://192.168.10.120/mcsrhub/mchub";
    var queryString = new Dictionary<string, string>
      {
        { "CreatedBy", "me" },
        { "UserId", "1234" },
        { "MachineName", Environment.MachineName }
      };

    var newUrl = new Uri(QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(url, queryString));

    connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl(newUrl) //"http://localhost:5289/mchub") //5181/chathub")
        .WithAutomaticReconnect()
        .Build();

    connection.Reconnecting += (sender) =>
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            var newMessage = "Attempting to reconnect...";
            messages.Items.Add(newMessage);
        });

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };

    connection.Reconnected += (sender) =>
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            var newMessage = "Reconnected to the server";
            messages.Items.Clear();
            messages.Items.Add(newMessage);
        });

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };

    connection.Closed += (sender) =>
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            var newMessage = "Connection Closed";
            messages.Items.Add(newMessage);
            openConnection.IsEnabled = true;
            sendMessage.IsEnabled = false;
        });

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
}

private async void openConnection_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    connection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) =>
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            var newMessage = $"{user}: {message}";
            messages.Items.Add(newMessage);
        });
    });

    try
    {

        await connection.StartAsync();
        messages.Items.Add("Connection Started");
        openConnection.IsEnabled = false;
        sendMessage.IsEnabled = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        messages.Items.Add(ex.Message);
    }
}

private async void sendMessage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await connection.InvokeAsync("SendMessage",
            "WPF Client", messageInput.Text);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        messages.Items.Add(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

If I use localhost as the url the connection is made OK. When I use that same WPF app on another machine on the LAN and use either the servers IP address or the servers MachineName I get:

*A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (192.168.10.120:80)*

I've disabled AVG running on both machines and checked that port 80 is open on the server. I added the cors references in but that made no difference.

Edit:
Hosted by IIS.

Comment: Where you host the asp.net core application, Kestrel or IIS or IISExpress ?

Answer (score 0):

Someone with more intricate knowledge that I will ever have will know that you can configure what ports IIS will listen on. I understand the default value is supposed to be empty which means it will listen on all ports however mine was set to "::" which means all IPv6 ports. "localhost" listens on IPv6 but it apparently converts IPv4 to IPv6 automatically (that means the code is built into the OS :-)).

To listen on IPv4 you need "0.0.0.0".

Executing "netsh http add iplisten ipaddress 192.168.10.120" fixed it for me.
[This website has details](https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-8/solve-iis-listener-problems) .

Answer (score -1):

**For Kestrel**

If you are using Kestrel, you can [check my answer and follow the steps to fix the issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1202208/using-kestrel-with-net-7-why-cant-i-access-asp-net?orderby=newest#answers).

**For IIS**

If you host the application in IIS, you should use your pc to ping `192.168.10.120` machine(If can't ping, you should check the 192.168.10.120 server pc if enabled ICMP).  Then double check the [inbound rule in your server](https://kb.diadem.in/how-to-configure-iis-to-access-website-using-ip-address_1080.html).

Comment: Thanks for your  input but those items were checked.