# Access ASP.NET Core 7 and Angular web app from other device

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0

I know this question has been already asked under other forms, I did my "homework" but I am stuck.

I have a .Net Core 7 + Angular 14 web app project as per Visual Studio 2022 template wizard.
If I am running the app locally I can access it without issues but if I am trying to access it from other device from the LAN, I get redirected to https://localhost:44417 and indeed the client device is not running anything at that address and port.

appsettings.Development.json

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "Token": "DUMMY SECRET KEY"
  },
  "RecaptchaConfig": {
    "SecretKey": "6LdMYNDUMMYAAFgmSWcLlIk8Fe0sio3xhFKIEWrZ",
    "ApiUrl": "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://0.0.0.0:5000"
      },
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://0.0.0.0:5001"
      }
    },
    "EndpointDefaults": {
      "Protocols": "Http1AndHttp2"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SqlConnection": "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=techdocs;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
  "Stripe": {    
    "SecretKey": "sk_test_51MikdGKAQ3DDUMMYERnJKwkAWf0lHeE5W0jwfCYnGWocpUlhxzH6xyLymf8gDFoWhfw5EDtQZSRtr5YP9ed00j07KcTHe"
  }
}
```

launchSettings.json

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "newTD": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7053;http://localhost:5053"
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
      }
    },
    "WSL": {
      "commandName": "WSL2",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "https://localhost:7053",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy",
        "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "https://localhost:7053;http://localhost:5053"
      },
      "distributionName": ""
    }
  },
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:12544",
      "sslPort": 44317
    }
  }
}
```

Program.cs

```
global using DataAccess.Data;
using DataAccess.DbAccess;
using DataAccess.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
//using newTD.Services;

using newTD.UserService;
using OrdersService;
using reCAPTCHA_V3;
using Stripe;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters;
using System.Text;
using TemplatesService;
using Whois;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
//builder.WebHost.UseUrls("https://0.0.0.0:5001");
StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = builder.Configuration["Stripe:SecretKey"];
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
builder.Services.Configure<RecaptchaConfig>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(RecaptchaConfig)));
builder.Services.AddTransient<ISqlDataAccess, SqlDataAccess>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ITemplateData, TemplateData>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ITemplateManagement, TemplateManagement>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserData, UserData>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IPricesData, PricesData>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IOrderData, OrderData>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ICustomerData, CustomerData>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IStripeService, StripeService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<UserModel>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IWhoisLookup ,WhoisLookup>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IRecaptchaService, RecaptchaService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ICalculateOrderAmount, CalculateOrderAmount>();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddControllers();

object value = builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8
                .GetBytes(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value)),
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };
    });
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{

    options.AddPolicy("FullAccessForAdminRole", policy =>
                  policy.RequireRole("admin"));

});
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Description = "Standard Authorization header using the Bearer scheme (\"bearer {token}\")",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
    });

    options.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();
});

var AllowStripeCORS = "AllowStripeCORS";
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{

    options.AddPolicy(name: AllowStripeCORS, policy =>
    {
        policy.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
        //policy.WithOrigins("https://checkout.stripe.com").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
        //.SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains();
    });

});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    //app.UseSwagger(x => x.SerializeAsV2 = true);
    //app.UseSwaggerUI(
    //    c =>
    //    {
    //        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
    //        c.RoutePrefix = "";
    //    });
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}


app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors(AllowStripeCORS);
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();


app.Run();
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> `44417` or `44317` ?

According your description, your front-end angular project call .net core api project. If it alway call `https://localhost:44317`, you should check the baseurl in your angular project. You should change it to `http(s)://192.168.1.1(ip_addr):44317`.

**Useful link**

[Solve IIS Listener Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76486233/7687666)